Properties of strings
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    char str[2];
    printf("Enter anything ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s", str);
}

What will become the output if I input a value which is greater than given array size and why ?

In "C" if your input is longer than the allocated memory of(in your case which is 2) it will cause undefined behavior, which means the program's behavior becomes unpredictable. This undefined behavior is caused by "buffer overflow".
"C" gives you flexibility to do that, but it does not guarantee what will happen with the program.

The may crash
The program may output strange results
It may work normally.


As space is needed for a null character, its more like "if your input is longer than  or as long as the allocated memory ...".  Input "a" is OK. Input "ab" is not.

Undefined behavior does not mean the program’s behavior becomes unpredictable. It means the C standard does not define the behavior. People familiar with the C implementation may be able to predict the behavior to a lesser or greater degree, depending on circumstances.


It may appear to work normally.



What will become the output if I input a value which is greater than given array size

As others have said, you will overrun the buffer. If you're not supposed to write to that memory, the outcome can be speculated but can't be predicted.
You can avoid overrunning a buffer by specifying a count of characters in your format parameter eg if your buffer is two %1s.
{
    char szPhone[21];

    puts("What is your phone number");
    scanf("%20s", szPhone);
}

Instead of scanf, you can also consider limiting length using fgets(szPhone, 20, stdin); or gets_s(szPhone, 20); (C11 onwards).

Please don't recommend non portable alternatives such as gets_s.

yeah pretty good question
scanf will just read(scan) the input and write into memory(str) until it encounter whitespace or end of input , because scanf doesn't check the memory size of array, however after the array limit too , it just writes into next memory segment
if next segment is empty , then works normal ,
if next segment contains some program data or some other data , then output may result in unexpected behaviour or progarm may crash

"if next segment is empty , then works normal" - that is actually not guaranteed. The whole issue with UB (undefined behavior) is that there is no point rationalizing about the bahavior of the program. Theoretically anything can happen.

@Leela "... until it encounter whitespace ..." --> leading whitespace does not stop input.  Leading whitespace is read and not saved and the reading continues.

@wohlstad: Re “The whole issue with UB (undefined behavior) is that there is no point rationalizing about the bahavior of the program”: No, that is not the whole issue with undefined behavior. The issue with undefined behavior is the C standard does not specify what happens. You know what often happens when a programmer sees a program misbehaving? The programmer uses its behavior as clues about what the bug is. They may examine it in a debugger (which is undefined by the C standard). They reason about the program and find the problem…

… Saying there is no point rationalizing about the behavior is just false, and that is not even considering that things besides the C standard may define the behavior, such as extensions to the C standard, requirements of the operating system, and more.

@EricPostpischil maybe my phrasing was not accurate. But I was referring to the answer that predicted that "if next segment is empty , then works normal". Wouldn't you agree it is incorrect due to the nature of UB ?

@wohlstad: No, for two reasons. One, the statement has a premise “next segment is empty,“ which the author apparently intends to mean the memory immediately after str is not in use for anything else in the program (and is mapped). If the premise is true, and the program is ordinarily linked with a standard C library, then scanf will indeed read data into that empty memory. This is a predictable behavior of ordinary C implementations…

… Two, as I wrote, programmers familiar with a C implementation know how its parts work and may be able to predict what the parts will do even though the C standard does not say what they will do.

@wohlstad: Re “Wouldn't you agree it is incorrect due to the nature of UB ?”: No. It is not the nature of undefined behavior that it is unpredictable. There is nothing in the C standard that specifies that. This is a myth erroneously spread on Stack Overflow. The nature of undefined behavior, as defined by the C standard, is only that the C standard makes no assertions about it. There is no assertion that it is unpredictable, uncontrollable, or undefinable by things other than the C standard. Those are not part of its nature…

… For one example, “undefined behavior” as defined and used by the C standard includes behavior that is defined by a compiler extension or behavior that is defined by a linker. These are examples of undefined behavior that are entirely predictable. What happens when you link a C routine with a C++ program is undefined behavior by the C standard, but companies around the world rely on it every day. What happens when a C program calls a graphics routine is undefined by the C standard but is predictable by the graphics documentation and the platform ABI.

@EricPostpischil I am quite sure in C++ UB contradicts predicability (this is a nice article about it). Is C different in that aspect ?

@wohlstad: Re “I am quite sure in C++ UB contradicts predicability”: No, that is false. The C++ standard specifies undefined behavior the same way the C standard does: it imposes no requirements. That includes no requirement that it is not predictable. The C++ standard even gives this example of undefined behavior: “behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment”.

@EricPostpischil But if it imposes no requirement, how can you predict the outcome reliably ? Did you see the link to the article I added to my previous comment ?)

@wohlstad: Re “But if it imposes no requirement, how can you predict the outcome reliably ?”: Because the fact the C or C++ standard imposes no requirements does not mean that nothing else does impose requirements nor that a human may not examine the situation and make their own analysis independently of the standards. Raymond Chen’s time travel argument is not relevant to this. It is about things that can happen; it does not assert that things other than what it discusses also can happen.

@EricPostpischil Re "programmers familiar with a C implementation know how its parts work and may be able to predict what the parts will do" - I read numerous posts here on SO, where very high rep users recommend never to rely on any specific tool behavior in cases of UB, because it can change (exactly because the standard does not mandate them).

@EricPostpischil I know you have a lot of knowledge in the area, and therefore suspect I am missing something here, because I don't understand your argument. As I wrote I saw a lot of posts here claiming otherwise (or at least so I understood).

@wohlstad: Re “I read numerous posts here on SO, where very high rep users recommend never to rely on any specific tool behavior in cases of UB, because it can change…”: As I wrote,  this is a myth spread erroneously on Stack Overflow. That is such a vague statement. It might apply to some things that are undefined behavior but it does not apply to all of them. It does not apply to things that are not documented by the C standard but are documented by other things. I could go on with other examples, but the fact some users have stated something is not a counterargument worth rebutting.

@wohlstad: Re “I don't understand your argument”: Do you not understand that a compiler may define things the C standard does not define? Do you not understand that an operating system may define what it does when a program accesses unmapped memory? Do you not understand that a platform ABI may define what happens when you link a C routine with a C++ program? This is all quite plain: The C standard does not say undefined behavior is unpredictable. In some of these situations, other documentation says what will happen. What basis is there for asserting the documented behavior is unpredictable?

@wohlstad: The C standard has the same example as C++: Undefined behavior may be “behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment.” Given that, I do not see how anybody can assert that undefined behavior is always unpredictable or that you cannot rationalize about it. The C standard does not say that. The C standard does say that undefined behavior may be behaving in a documented manner, which is therefore predictable and can be reasoned about. There is no authoritative basis for asserting undefined behavior cannot be reasoned about.

@EricPostpischil I understand that all the entities you mentioned may define things the C standard does not. But I was under the impression that it's not advisable to rely on these things, because these entities can change their behavior in this apsect at any time (without breaking their conformance with the standard). Therefore I thought that rationalyzing about a programs behavior is on solid ground only if the behavior is well defined by the standard.

@EricPostpischil I do understand that if you are aware of a specific documented aspect on a specific platform that you are using, you can indeed predict the behavior. But most of the questions here are not restricted to a specific compiler and platform.

@EricPostpischil the current question is a good example. It does not mention any specific compiler, OS etc. And so predicting the outcome in case of UB seem problematic to me.

@EricPostpischil having said that, I understand your objection to the automatic claim that "UB => nazal deamons".

@wohlstad: Re “But I was under the impression that it's not advisable to rely on these things, because these entities can change their behavior in this apsect at any time”: That is like saying you cannot rely on behavior the C standard defines because the C standard can change at any time. Well, it cannot; it takes time, and there is plenty of notice. GCC has documented its extensions, so it cannot change those without time and notice. Fundamental operating system features, like memory protection, are well established and will not change. How compilers and linkers interact is well established…

… and will change somewhat (e.g., improved link-time optimization) over time, but we can nonetheless guarded rely on their behaviors. Compiler design affects some undefined behaviors; compilers work by syntactic analysis, grammatical analysis, generating a semantic representation of code, optimizing it, and generating assembly. They are not black boxes with unknown workings. Those workings are unlikely to change drastically, and some of the behaviors we see from them are characteristic of their design structure, and we can rely on that.

@EricPostpischil fair enough. But this only applies to questions bound to a specific compiler/platform (unlike this one).

@wohlstad: Re “But this only applies to questions bound to a specific compiler/platform”: (a) So what? “If you are on a general-purpose operating system, attempting to access memory outside of your mapped virtual address space will result in an exception” is a prediction, and hence the “undefined behavior” is not unpredictable. (b) Many of these things apply broadly cross-platform.

@wohlstad: Re “the current question is a good example. It does not mention any specific compiler, OS etc. And so predicting the outcome in case of UB seem problematic to me.”: It is not problematic; it is a good example of where software architecture enables us to make a prediction. By and large, scanf is implemented in a library that is linked into the program. Supposing it is, then, for scanf("%s",str);, scanf receives only the address of the format string and the address of the destination buffer…

… Since it does not know the size of the destination buffer, and it must work if the buffer is large, we can figure out what it will do if the input string overruns str. It must, by reason and knowledge that it is linked separately, continue to write in memory after str. We know that, even though the C standard does not impose such a requirement. It is a logical, necessary conclusion from the software architecture. If that memory is mapped and otherwise unused, it must “work” in that the string will be written into that memory.

@EricPostpischil your analysis is surely correct from a technical point of view. But we should still avoid UB whenever we can (at least as a general rule, there might be exceptions). And understanding that something is UB is the first step. Having read all you wrote I understand better now that saying "UB => anything can happen" is not really always correct. But IMHO it is not such a bad simplification, that can help to keep us away from these places.
